# Excel Function to get an entire column based on a value within a row

Tags: excel

What I want to do is something like this: "Get column where value in row 1 is equal to "X"". Then I can do additional stuff using that column like "Count all rows in this column where value is not "Y"".

Comment: Do you want the 'column' as part of a formula? Or do you want it as an object variable in VBA?

Comment: Did you find any of the answers useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this below to find the desired value in a given row.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Row As Integer, FindWhat As String
    Row = 1
    FindWhat = "1"

    Rows(Row & ":" & Row).Select
    Selection.Find(What:=FindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

If 1 is found in cell E1, the result will be $E$1.

Answer (score 0):

```
so if you have columns
 A B C D
  -------
1|2 3
2|3
3|2
4|2
```

And you want to count a the rows that only has value 3 in A use =countif(a:a, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Hi is this a vba type thing or formula based....?  If formula i would just use the match formula...say you want to find the column position where the word "dog" appears in row 1

Match("dog",1:1,0)

Then you could possibly build on this formula with the countif formula for your purpose originally.

If vba the first answer is solid from zedfoxis